# MySQL get info from three tables

Tags: mysql

I'm new to SQL so please bear with me. 
I'm writing a loginscript and want to get info from three tables. The problem is that this query only returns one value from table3. 
Could somebody give me some pointers, please.

```
SELECT
    table1.id,
    table1.username,
    table1.password,
    table1.email, 
    table2.image,   
    table3.intValue,
    table3.textValue,
    table3.dateValue
FROM
    table1
LEFT JOIN
    table2

ON
    table1.id = table2.userId

LEFT JOIN
    table3
ON
    table1.id = table3.userId
        AND columnName='sex' OR columnName='birthdate' OR columnName='realname'

WHERE 
    table1.email = $username
OR 
    table1.username = $username
```

columnName='sex' is an integer (intValue)
columnName='birthdate' is a date (dateValue)
columnName='realname' is a string (textValue)

Thank you.

Comment: why would a login table record gender? Or Birthdate? Also one of your tables seems to be key-value pairs. I probably wouldn't do that.

Comment: I want to return some user profile information at the same time the login is done

Comment: Again I would ask the question: why does a user profile record gender?

Comment: Could you please explain the purpose of this line: `AND columnName='sex' OR columnName='birthdate' OR columnName='realname'` i.e. what are you trying to achive with this? And what is this? `table3.intValue, table3.textValue, table3.dateValue` It seems like your approach is inherently wrong naming your table columns like that. Then you say something about intValue, dateValue, textValue... I recommend starting over and use 'real-world' naming... Why name a column 'dateValue' when you are describing a users birthdate???

Comment: Ah I think I know what you are trying to do. Table1 contains login+pass, table2 contains user (profile?) images and table3 contains profile fields. I suggest giving users a set of profile fields and putting it all in one table (or a seperate table containing a set of standard nullable profile fields). Perhaps use foreign key constraints to give users a profile image etc. The reason table3 only returns 'one value' is because mysql cannot give you multiple rows in one row. [EAV is an anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)

Comment: This is not my db design. I'm working with an existing database. Table3 looks something like this:<br>

| id  | questionName | userId | textValue | intValue | dateValue |<br>
| 1   | realname     | 1      | Thomas    |          |           |<br>
| 2   | sex          | 1      |           | 1        |           |<br>
| 3   | birthdate    | 1      |           |          |1971-11-24 |<br>

Comment: Terrible! Start over and slap the person who designed this database! Or give up getting user data in the same query as login.

Comment: Point taken @AmazingDreams

Comment: [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) is something you can try (requires some extra processing). There are some limits like maximum string length. This could give you a string like e.g. `|realname:thomas|birthdate:1971-11-24|gender:1|`. With some processing you can split these values by `|` and `:` and get key-value pairs which can be used like rows.

Comment: @AmazingDreams - Thx, I'll have a go at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your query (formatted so I can read it better):

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.username, t1.password, t1.email, 
       t2.image, t3.intValue, t3.textValue, t3.dateValue
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t1.id = t1.userId LEFT JOIN
     table3 t3
     ON t1.id = t3.userId AND
        columnName='sex' OR columnName='birthdate' OR columnName='realname'
WHERE t1.email = $username OR t1.username = $username ;
```

One problem is the `OR` condition on `table3`.  This is evaluated as:

```
    ON (t1.id = t3.userId AND columnName='sex') OR columnName='birthdate' OR columnName='realname';
```

SQL doesn't read mind.  It invokes precedence rules.  The condition would be best stated as:

```
     ON t1.id = t3.userId AND
        columnName in ('sex', 'birthdate', 'realname');
```

However, I don't think that is causing the problem of one row.  If anything, that would multiply the number of rows.

It would seem that you want to get the values all in one row, whereas your query is going to return a separate row for each row in `table3`. If so, you should use `group by`, with appropriate aggregation.  The final query would be:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.username, t1.password, t1.email, 
       t2.image,
       max(case when columnName = 'sex' then t3.intValue end) as sex,
       max(case when columnName = 'realname' then t3.textValue end) as realname,
       max(case when columnName = 'birthdate' then t3.dateValue end) as birthdate
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t1.id = t1.userId LEFT JOIN
     table3 t3
     ON t1.id = t3.userId AND
        columnName in ('sex', 'birthdate', 'realname')
WHERE t1.email = $username OR t1.username = $username
GROUP BY t1.id;
```

Comment: This is the solution to my problem. Thank you for taking the time.